# ms-access: brackets around a listbox?

Tags: ms-access, vba

these are both listboxes. why does one have brackets around it?

```
[relationslct].Value = other_relations_lst.Value
```

Comment: More alarming than the brackets is the lack of an explicit parent for your listbox, i.e., Me!relcationshlct. The .Value is unnecessary, as that's the default property of all Access controls. So, "Me!relationslct = Me!other_relations_lst" should do the job with the minimum typing and the desired level of specificity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets are required for names which could confuse Access ... say if the name includes spaces or punctuation characters.  And brackets also help to avoid confusing Access if the name is the same as a reserved word (like Date, for example).

However, I don't see any need for brackets around *relationslct*.  They don't cause any harm, but I prefer to get rid of them whenever they're not actually needed.

If your question includes "how did they get in there in the first place?" ... I got no clue.